# Locked out of WordPress after changing to HTTPS – Google Cloud VM

Tags: wp-admin

I'm locked out of my website and all admin access after changing the URL from HTTP to HTTPS. I tried connecting via FileZilla FTP, but that did not work either.

I'm using a **Google Cloud VM with WordPress Click to Deploy**.

Comment: You should elaborate more. How exactly did you change the URL?

Comment: have you tried to update the siteurl and home values in {prefix}_options (wp_options) in the database to https yet?